# Get all cells data from row in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<DataGrid Name="gridAnagrafiche"  Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding listAnagrafiche, ElementName=window}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="rowAnagrafiche_DoubleClick"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Codice" Binding="{Binding cod}" Width="0.7*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gruppo" Binding="{Binding gruppo}" Width="1*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ragione Sociale" Binding="{Binding nome}" Width="1.3*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

this is my xaml

I'm stuck.. I can't get all data cells from clicked row..

After click I should open "panelCreaAnagrafica" with setted textbox

```
private void rowAnagrafiche_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        hideAllPanels();
        this.panelCreaAnagrafica.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        var labelTemp = (TextBox)this.panelCreaAnagrafica.FindName("txtCod");
        labelTemp.Text = (FIRST DATA CELL);
        labelTemp = (TextBox)this.panelCreaAnagrafica.FindName("txtGruppo");
        labelTemp.Text = (SECOND DATA CELL);
        labelTemp = (TextBox)this.panelCreaAnagrafica.FindName("txtRagSoc");
        labelTemp.Text = (THIRD DATA CELL);
    }
```

Comment: Could you add code-behind to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cast the sender argument of the event handler to a DataGridRow and then cast its DataContext to your type with the "cod", "gruppo", "nome" properties, e.g.:

```
private void rowAnagrafiche_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow row = sender as DataGridRow;
    if (row != null)
    {
        dynamic dataObject = row.DataContext;
        string nome = dataObject.nome;
    }
}
```